# Why does this numpy construct work and is there a more correct way of doing it

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy to extract faces from tetrahdra defined by vertex indices.
I have an initial array defining the tehrahedra toplogy

```
tetrahedra = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

For each tetrahedra I identify the faces using mask array

```
face1 = [True, True, True, False]
face2 = [True, True, False, True]
face3 = [False, True, True, True]
face4 = [True, False, True, True]
```

And I find the following numpy expression yields face defnitions for each tetrahedra

```
faces = tetrahedra[:,np.reshape(np.r_[tetrahedra[0][face1 ],tetrahedra[0][face2 ],tetrahedra[0][face3 ],tetrahedra[0][face4 ]], (-1,3))]
```

EDIT : Thanks to @npaulj I now see that this only appears to work because tetrahedra[0] in the indexing notation is actually [0, 1, 2, 3]. This is better expressed by changing the boolean masks to direct index masks as follows,

```
mask1_ = np.array([0, 1, 2])
mask2_ = np.array([0, 1, 3])
mask3_ = np.array([1, 2, 3])
mask4_ = np.array([0, 2, 3])
```

and then updating the expression to

```
faces = tetrahedra[:,np.reshape(np.r_[face1_, face2_, face3_, face4_], (-1,3))]
```

Now my question is, how is this actually working and is there a preferred/faster way of doing this operation?  The output is shown below

THanks in advance for any help with this. I'm tempted to just live with it since it appears to work, but I can't fugre out why it works which worries me.....

```
[[[0 1 2]
  [0 1 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [0 2 3]]
 [[1 2 3]
  [1 2 4]
  [2 3 4]
  [1 3 4]]
 [[2 3 4]
  [2 3 5]
  [3 4 5]
  [2 4 5]]
```

]

**edit**
Cleaned up version is,

```
face_masks = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3],[0, 2, 3]])
faces = tetrahedra[:,face_masks]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the intermediate steps?  If I wrote an answer I'd show those steps one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the intermediate steps:

```
In [77]: tetrahedra = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]])
    ...: face1 = [True, True, True, False]
    ...: face2 = [True, True, False, True]
    ...: face3 = [False, True, True, True]
    ...: face4 = [True, False, True, True]

In [78]: tetrahedra[0]
Out[78]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [79]: tetrahedra[0][face1]
Out[79]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

`r_` concatenates these 4 selections into one array:

```
In [80]: np.r_[tetrahedra[0][face1 ],tetrahedra[0][face2 ],tetrahedra[0][face3 ],tetrahedra[0][face4 ]]
Out[80]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3])

In [81]: np.reshape(np.r_[tetrahedra[0][face1 ],tetrahedra[0][face2 ],tetrahedra[0][face3
    ...:  ],tetrahedra[0][face4 ]], (-1,3))
Out[81]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

And finally just use that to index the columns dimension of `tetrahedra`.  Index a (3,4) with this (4,3) produces a (3,4,3).

`vstack` could also be used to concatenate the selections, but that's a minor change:

```
In [82]: np.vstack([tetrahedra[0][face1 ],tetrahedra[0][face2 ],tetrahedra[0][face3 ],tet
    ...: rahedra[0][face4 ]])
Out[82]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

### edit

Or if you don't want to count on `tetrahedra[0]` being [0,1,2,3], you could just seek the indices of the `True` elements:

```
In [106]: np.nonzero([face1,face2,face3,face4])
Out[106]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3]))
```

The 2nd element of that tuple `[1]` is the same indices you with `r_`.

```
In [122]: idx = np.nonzero([face1,face2,face3,face4])
In [123]: idx[1]
Out[123]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3])
In [124]: tetrahedra[np.arange(3)[:,None],idx[1]]
Out[124]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5]])
In [125]: tetrahedra[np.arange(3)[:,None],idx[1]].reshape(3,4,3)
Out[125]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [0, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [1, 3, 4]],

       [[2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 5],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [2, 4, 5]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for ths reply. I think my original question could have been clearer..... I understand how the single row operations work - concatenting the masks. What I donlt understan is how the tetrahedra[0] part seems to be able to access the first axis members?  How is that[0] indexing working?

Comment: Because the example produces the concatenated masks for EVERY tetrahedra in the array,not just the first?

Comment: The indexing created with `face...` uses just the 1st row of `tetrahedra` - same `[0]` for each of the 4 `face` arrays.

Comment: But when I look at the ouput, I see the mask is atcually correctly applied to EVERY row in tetrahedra? Not just the first

Comment: The behavior is like "apply_along_axis()". This is the behavior I actually want by the way - ny end goal is to convert tetrahedral faces defined by their corner indices into tetrahedra faces defined by their face ids - 1,2,3, or 4

Comment: OK I get it now. I was being dumb. This whole thing only appears to work across rows because the first tetrahdra vertex indices are 0,1,2,3. There's a much saner notation that I can now see that I'll show in another answer - sice I canlt figure out how to add it to a comment.....

Comment: Yes if you don't want to count on that row, you could just use the `np.nonzero(...)[1]`, as shown in my latest edit.

Comment: Yes - I see that. ALso, I can combine all of the masks into a single array and clean the whole thing up. Thanks for the hellp. Nex step is to supply a face vertex array for each row and get the face index back of the mask that matches......